# Difference in font rendering between iTerm and Terminal.app

Tags: terminal, font, iterm

I've just installed iTerm 3.2.0. I'm using default settings and noticed that fonts look slightly different, compared to Terminal.app. A bit thinner, and glyph heights (or maybe distances between lines) are smaller. In fullscreen mode, Terminal.app fits 59 lines on the screen, while iTerm fits 65. Why is that?

I'm running macOS Mojave, with `Use font smoothing when available` on. Also checked that in iTerm's Preferences, under Profiles->Text, `Use thin strokes` is set to `Never`.

---

update: Ventura 13.6

Terminal settings:

[image: terminal settings]

[image: terminal font settings]

iTerm2 (Build 3.4.20) settings:

[image]

Yet Terminal looks great

[image: terminal]

iTerm2 looks kind of meh

[image]

Compare the "i" in "Login". In Terminal it's clear and strong. In iTerm2 it's thin and janky

In both settings above, anti-alias is off. Turning on in both iTerm2 gets slightly less janky but it's still much less strong than Terminal

Terminal (anti-aliased):

[image: terminal anti-aliased]

iTerm2 (anti-aliased):

[image: iterm2 anti-aliases]

What settings will get iTerm2 to look the same as Terminal?

Comment: Did you check the line spacing and character spacing under the font selection button?

Comment: Sure that you have the same font at the same size selected?

Comment: @jmh - just checked, both horizontal and vertical are set to 100%

Comment: @LangLangC - yes, it's default Menlo Regular 11pt

Comment: I have the same problem and still can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Under the iTerm2 setting for Text Rendering, there are options for "Use thin strokes for anti-aliased text". On my machine, if I change from "On Retina Displays" to "Never", the terminal's text fattens up a bit, and looks pretty much the same as in Terminal.app.